# PostMessage Not working with allocated console in winform app

Tags: c++, windows, c++-cli

SO I got a `c++/cli` form app which has a checkbox(debug in chinese) with the name of `checkBox3` inside my app:

[image]

This is the code of the checkbox:

```cpp
private: System::Void checkBox3_CheckedChanged(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        //set the debug flag
        g.debug = !g.debug;
        HWND allocatedConsole = NULL;
        if (this->checkBox3->Checked == true)
        {
            AllocConsole();
            freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);//use cout
        }
        else {
            allocatedConsole = GetConsoleWindow();
            std::cout << allocatedConsole << std::endl;
            PostMessageA(allocatedConsole, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
            FreeConsole();
        }
    }
```

Which does that whenever I click on the checkbox, it allocates a console and then when I  un-check the checkbox, it stores the H-window of the console using `GetConsoleWindow` function inside `allocatedConsole` and then tries to close `allocatedConsole` remotely using the `PostMessageA` function with the `WM_CLOSE` message and finally it free's it.

**However when I un-check the checkbox it free's the console but does not close it at all**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try sending a `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message with `wParam` = `SC_CLOSE`.  This more closely mimics selecting 'Close' from the system menu.

Comment: But note the race condition. When the console is closed, it sends a `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` to all attached processes via the session server, and for this event the server gives the process 5 seconds to exit before it forcefully terminates it. To necessarily avoid this, the program needs to detach from the console via `FreeConsole` before posting the close message to the console window.